# How to get list of apps with detail and icon installed on iOs device with ios 9?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to get all installed app icon and it's detail parameter, how can I get it and open that app via my app page.

### I can get list of installed app using this code:

```
Class LSApplicationWorkspace_class = objc_getClass("LSApplicationWorkspace");
NSObject* workspace = [LSApplicationWorkspace_class performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(@"defaultWorkspace")];
NSMutableArray *array = [workspace performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(@"allApplications")];

NSMutableArray *Applist = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (id lsApplicationProxy in array) {
    if(nil != [lsApplicationProxy performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(@"itemName")]){
        [Applist addObject:[lsApplicationProxy performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(@"itemName")]];
    }
}
NSLog(@" Applications List  : \n %@",Applist);
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to open an other app from your app, you need to find the URL scheme of this app. Each URL scheme is different and can't be found if app developer don't send it to you. For example, for Twitter:

```
NSURL *twitterURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"fb://profile/<profile_id>"];
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:twitterURL]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:twitterURL];
}
```

Comment: You must add this URL schemes to the project plist file. Due to privacy concerns of Apple you can only use 50 schemes.